# Cannot delete parent table row due to foreign-key constraint in children table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Am Using Hibernate 5.6 and have a problem with cascading:

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE public.srm_t_questionnaire_answer (
    rowguid bigserial NOT NULL,
    qa_fk_rfq_id int4 NULL,
    qa_fk_quote_id int4 NULL,
    qa_fk_supplier_id int4 NULL,
    qa_fk_questionnaire_id int4 NULL,
    qa_fk_question_id int4 NULL,
    qa_creation_date timestamp NOT NULL,
    qa_creation_user varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    qa_modification_date timestamp NOT NULL,
    qa_modification_user varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT srm_t_questionnaire_answer_pk PRIMARY KEY (rowguid)
);

CREATE TABLE public.srm_t_questionnaire_answer_value (
    fk_answer_id int4 NOT NULL,
    fk_option_id int4 NOT NULL,
    a_text_value text NULL,
    a_numeric_value numeric NULL,
    a_date_value timestamptz NULL,
    a_doc_valid_from timestamptz NULL,
    a_doc_valid_to timestamptz NULL,
    a_fk_doc_id int4 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT srm_t_questionnaire_answer_value_pk PRIMARY KEY (fk_answer_id, fk_option_id)
);

ALTER TABLE public.srm_t_questionnaire_answer_value ADD CONSTRAINT srm_t_questionnaire_answer_value_fk FOREIGN KEY (fk_answer_id) REFERENCES public.srm_t_questionnaire_answer(rowguid);
ALTER TABLE public.srm_t_questionnaire_answer_value ADD CONSTRAINT srm_t_questionnaire_answer_value_fk_1 FOREIGN KEY (fk_option_id) REFERENCES public.srm_t_question_option(rowguid);
```

Mapping looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "srm_t_questionnaire_answer")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SrmQsQuestionnaireAnswerVOImpl extends AbstractBasePropertiesImpl implements SrmQsQuestionnaireAnswerVO {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "srm_t_questionnaire_answer_rowguid_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "srm_t_questionnaire_answer_rowguid_seq", sequenceName = "srm_t_questionnaire_answer_rowguid_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name="rowguid")
    private Long rowguid;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "answer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<SrmQsQuestionnaireAnswerValueVOImpl> answerValue;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "srm_t_questionnaire_answer_value")
@IdClass(SrmQsQuestionnaireAnswerValueVOImplId.class)
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SrmQsQuestionnaireAnswerValueVOImpl extends AbstractBasePropertiesImpl implements SrmQsQuestionnaireAnswerValueVO {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_answer_id")
    private SrmQsQuestionnaireAnswerVOImpl answer;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_option_id")
    private SrmQsQuestionOptionVOImpl option;
}
```

When I try to delete an row from answer table which is referenced as foreign key in answer_value table, I get the error:

```
var answer = new SrmQsQuestionnaireAnswerVOImpl();
answer.setRowguid(1L);
answerService.getObjectDAO().delete(answer);
```

> ERROR: update or delete on table "srm_t_questionnaire_answer" violates
> foreign key constraint "srm_t_questionnaire_answer_value_fk" on table
> "srm_t_questionnaire_answer_value"

Of course, before deleting the answer, Hibernate should check if there are answer_values with that particular ID and delete them first. But obviously that does not happen. Any idea what's wrong here?

**Edit:** When I try to load the entity before deleting via findById, I get this error which I'm not entirely sure where that comes from:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set
> com.cl.myapp.srm.qs.business.impl.SrmQsQuestionVOImpl field
> com.cl.myapp.srm.qs.business.impl.SrmQsQuestionnaireAnswerVOImpl.question
> to
> com.cl.myapp.srm.qs.business.impl.SrmQsQuestionVOImpl$HibernateProxy$lkSYs8mN

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you just create a new instance of the entity instead of reading it from the database. That's why JPA can't properly delete it. Try similar to this:

```
Answer answer = service.findById(1L);
service.delete(answer);
```

**After you last edit:** it looks like you have more entities then you are showing code for. The error comes from yet another entity SrmQsQuestionVOImpl. I would suggest to carefully analyze your data structure and the current data in the database. For example for every FK in one table of a relation a corresponding entry with this PK in another table must exist. Otherwise remove the FK directly in the database.